# How can I do own increment value in mysql

Tags: mysql, increment

I'm struggling to do proper sql script to increment field on specific way.

Those two script are without any exception, but nothing happened on the results.

Script 1:

```
UPDATE 
   myTable T1, 
   (
       SELECT id, 
              (@s:=@s+1) AS seq
       FROM myTable, (SELECT (@s:=0) AS s ) s 
       WHERE infotext IS NULL ORDER BY grouptext
   ) T2

SET sequence = seq

WHERE T1.id = T2.id
```

Script 2:

```
UPDATE myTable AS target

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT supfault_id, 
           (@s:=@s+1) AS seq 
    FROM myTable, (SELECT (@s:=0) AS s ) s 
    WHERE infotext IS NULL ORDER BY grouptext
) AS ordered ON ordered.id = target.id

SET sequence = seq
```

Comment: what do you want to do? update record after insert a new one? or get the last value then increment by one?

Comment: I have table with records with added new column. 
All values are set as 0.

And I need to increment these values by specific way. 
Records have own sequence value.

Comment: Currently I need to do alphabetic sort and use sorted data on the view. 
But I can't to do alphabetic sort on the front end, because in the future, user will have an option to resequence it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subqueries working well separately, so I wondered why I can't update my sequence value by seq from subquery.

I'm not expert, but I felt that need to be used some virtual table for my subquery.

Here is solution for inner join case:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE supportGroupSeqcalculation AS 
   SELECT supfault_id, 
          (@s:=@s+1) AS seq
   FROM myTable, (SELECT (@s:=0) AS s ) s 
   WHERE infotext IS NULL
   ORDER BY grouptext;

UPDATE myTable AS target
INNER JOIN supportGroupSeqcalculation AS ordered ON ordered.supfault_id = target.supfault_id
SET sequence = seq;  

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE supportGroupSeqcalculation;
```

We can get into temporary table specific order and record it as sequence value.

It is not necessarily to drop temporary table, it exists only in current session.

Answer (score 0):

This one get the last desc value from table1 and increment by one then update the table2:

```
set @inc = 0;
select cast(valToIncrement as signed) into @inc from
(select REPLACE(fkid,' ','') as valToIncrement from tbl_1 ORDER BY fkid)as a ORDER BY valToIncrement desc limit 1;

update tbl_2 set fkid = @inc + 1 where fkid = 122;
```

Comment: Just replace the real name of your table and it's column name.

Comment: A little hard to read, but I got your idea. I think that does exist more clear way how to do incrementation.

In real I need to do sort on specific way, therefore I using in my scripts subselect to do update. In the subselect I can get what I need in order I need and just do update of sequence value by seq from subselect.